# Do PCA transform/project functions from sklearn/opencv libraries retain the order of the original data set?

Tags: opencv, scikit-learn, pca

I was wondering if the `transform()` from [`sklearn.decomposition.PCA`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.transform) or `project()` from [C++ opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d8d/classcv_1_1PCA.html#a67c9a3f8fe804f40be58c88a3ae73f41) rearrange the results from the original data.

pca.py:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# read csv into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
columns=['x', 'y']

pca = PCA()
pca.fit(df)

t = pca.transform(df)
print(t)
```

sample.csv:

```
x,y
2.5,2.4
0.5,0.7
2.2,2.9
1.9,2.2
3.1,3.0
2.3,2.7
2,1.6
1,1.1
1.5,1.6
1.1,0.9
```

transformed data:

```
[[-0.82797019 -0.17511531]
 [ 1.77758033  0.14285723]
 [-0.99219749  0.38437499]
 [-0.27421042  0.13041721]
 [-1.67580142 -0.20949846]
 [-0.9129491   0.17528244]
 [ 0.09910944 -0.3498247 ]
 [ 1.14457216  0.04641726]
 [ 0.43804614  0.01776463]
 [ 1.22382056 -0.16267529]]
```

I wanted to ensure that `(2.5, 2.4)` corresponds to `(-0.82797019, -0.17511531)`, `(0.5,0.7)` to `(1.77758033,0.14285723)` and so on.

OpenCV PCA class' `project()` outputs the same. But the eigenvalues seem to get rearranged in descending order automatically from OpenCV library so I was wondering if these transformed/projected data are arranged accordingly as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes, order of samples is the same with that of projections/transform. Eigenvalues, on the other hand, are always sorted in descending order in both `sklearn` and `OpenCv` and pretty much all PCA implementations since that is the gist of PCA: to retain largest eigenvalues.